# How do I compute an aggregate calculation on similar sql elements in a table?

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am having a problem with generating the SQL task I want.

My goal is to have a margin calculation per each item category. The code works, but in some cases, an item might have four different costs, so when I execute the query, I get four lines with each of them the margin calculation. I would like to have one that summarizes everything.

How can I do it? I tried removing the cost from the selection at the beginning and group by at the end, but I get an error saying that it is not a valid group by expression.
If possible, I would like to know how I could compute the margin for all the entries in the table, regardless of their cost and price.

```sql
SELECT 
  pc.product_description,
  round(li.price,2) as price,
  round(li.cost_price,2) as cost_price,
  SUM(li.quantity) as Total_Items_sold,
  round(SUM(li.quantity)*li.price-SUM(li.quantity)*li.cost_price,2) as Gross_Margin_$,
FROM 
  product_description as pc
LEFT JOIN orders as li ON 
  pc.product_id = li.SKU
WHERE 
  pc.product_description = 'Sweater' and 
  li.state = 'complete' and 
  li.created_at like '2019%'
GROUP BY 
  pc.product_description, 
  li.price, 
  li.cost_price
```

Comment: Hi @Icasucci , can you give us some example data ? Also, we need the info what database do you use ? Oracle, MySQL or something else... Thanks!

Comment: @lcasucci . . . Your query refers to `so` but nothing has that alias.  That makes your question really hard to follow.

Comment: One possibility is to use what you have as a subquery and then group by product_description to aggregate the rest as you wish for the summary.  Another option would possibly be to remove price and cost_price both from the select and from the group by.

Comment: @VBokšić it is in SQL!

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you for spotting that - I could not paste the original one because it was nested to other tables that are not necessary to answer the question I posted.

Comment: @Eric it does :)))

Comment: `SQL` just just a language used by multiple dbms vendors.  Each vendor has their own specific syntax.  It's useless if someone post a solution, but you can't use it because it's on the wrong dbms.

Comment: @lcasucci check again what Eric wrote. And also, you can write: "it is in SQL." and not "it is in SQL!" especially when you are not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating some dummy data for your scenario:

```
create table product_description
(
    product_id varchar(10),
    product_description varchar(50)
)

create table orders
(
    SKU varchar(10),
    price decimal(10,2),
    cost_price decimal(10,2),
    quantity int,
    [state] varchar(10),
    created_at varchar(20) -- Ugly, but you're treating this as a string in your query
)

insert into product_description 
values 
('PRO001', 'Sweater'),
('PRO002', 'Jeans'),
('PRO003', 'Shoes'),
('PRO004', 'Dress'),
('PRO005', 'Blouse')

insert into orders
values
('PRO001',29.99,13.50,3,'complete','2019-11-19'),
('PRO001',26.99,12.50,1,'complete','2018-06-18'),
('PRO004',37.99,20.75,2,'complete','2019-11-17'),
('PRO003',19.99,6.50,10,'complete','2019-11-16'),
('PRO003',19.99,6.25,5,'complete','2019-11-15'),
('PRO002',23.99,10.50,13,'complete','2019-11-14'),
('PRO004',37.99,21.00,3,'complete','2019-11-13'),
('PRO001',29.99,13.50,7,'incomplete','2019-11-12'),
('PRO003',18.99,5.50,9,'complete','2019-11-11'),
('PRO004',39.99,23.50,18,'complete','2019-11-11'),
('PRO005',19.99,11.50,23,'complete','2019-11-10'),
('PRO001',29.99,13.50,12,'complete','2019-11-09')
```

Resulting in the following data in these tables:

```
select * from product_description

/----------------------------------\
| product_id | product_description |
|------------|---------------------|
| PRO001     | Sweater             |
| PRO002     | Jeans               |
| PRO003     | Shoes               |
| PRO004     | Dress               |
| PRO005     | Blouse              |
\----------------------------------/

select * from orders

/------------------------------------------------------------------\
| SKU    | price | cost_price | quantity |   state    | created_at |
|--------|-------|------------|----------|------------|------------|
| PRO001 | 29.99 |   13.50    |     3    | complete   | 2019-11-19 |
| PRO001 | 26.99 |   12.50    |     1    | complete   | 2018-06-18 |
| PRO004 | 37.99 |   20.75    |     2    | complete   | 2019-11-17 |
| PRO003 | 19.99 |    6.50    |    10    | complete   | 2019-11-16 |
| PRO003 | 19.99 |    6.25    |     5    | complete   | 2019-11-15 |
| PRO002 | 23.99 |   10.50    |    13    | complete   | 2019-11-14 |
| PRO004 | 37.99 |   21.00    |     3    | complete   | 2019-11-13 |
| PRO001 | 29.99 |   13.50    |     7    | incomplete | 2019-11-12 |
| PRO003 | 18.99 |    5.50    |     9    | complete   | 2019-11-11 |
| PRO004 | 39.99 |   23.50    |    18    | complete   | 2019-11-11 |
| PRO005 | 19.99 |   11.50    |    23    | complete   | 2019-11-10 |
| PRO001 | 29.99 |   13.50    |    12    | complete   | 2019-11-09 |
\------------------------------------------------------------------/
```

The following query gives you what you want, I believe:

```
select
    pd.product_description as Product,
    sum((o.quantity * o.price) - (o.quantity * o.cost_price)) as GrossMargin
from orders o
left join product_description pd on o.SKU = pd.product_id
group by pd.product_description
```

Results:

```
/-----------------------\
| Product | GrossMargin |
|---------|-------------|
| Blouse  | 195.27      |
| Dress   | 382.27      |
| Jeans   | 175.37      |
| Shoes   | 325.01      |
| Sweater | 377.27      |
\-----------------------/
```

If you then want to further filter the results on a specific year or product, you can:

```
select
    pd.product_description as Product,
    sum((o.quantity * o.price) - (o.quantity * o.cost_price)) as GrossMargin
from orders o
left join product_description pd on o.SKU = pd.product_id
where o.created_at like '2019%'
and pd.product_description = 'Sweater'
group by pd.product_description
```

Which you'll see, excludes the order from 2018:

```
/-----------------------\
| Product | GrossMargin |
|---------|-------------|
| Sweater | 362.78      |
\-----------------------/
```